# Growth rate of functions

Tags: algorithms

These are the functions that I have:

$$\log n, (\log n)^2, \ln(m), n^\frac{1}3+\log n, \sqrt{n}, \frac{n}{\log n},( \frac{3}2)^n $$

From what I understand, this is what I come up from the lowest to highest growth rate.

$$\log n < (\log n)^2 < \ln(m)< n^\frac{1}3+\log n < \sqrt{n} < \frac{n}{\log n} <( \frac{3}2)^n $$

But I am not sure this is correct, is there anyone could help to explain how to solve these ? Putting in number as examples definitely helps.

Thank You!

Comment: What is $m$ there?

Comment: my bad, it is just a typo. It is like n.

Comment: In that case, $\ln(n)$ is not in the correct spot in the (otherwise correct) inequalities.

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: @GregMartin Didn't you mean $\ln(m)?$